# MS Word bibliography order

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I've recently started using bibliography in MS Word and it causes me trouble.

All the references are ordered (at least it seems so) in order of it's usage in the paper. It appears like this in any numerical citation style.

I need them to be ordered alphabetically and I can't understand how to get it.

Maybe someone has had this issue and can help me?

Comment: There are multiple bibliography standards which one of you selected?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

- In Word, References pane, Citations & Bibliography group, click the
  "Manage Sources" button
- Change the sort order to "Sort by Title"
- Click OK.

You may also examine the details of any citation in the list by selecting it
and clicking "Edit...".